# how to use the linux access command and what is the difference with test command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I went through the Linux man page for `access` command, but not sure about the application of the command.

Can someone explain this.

Can it be used like this:

```
access -f filename;
```

If i want to check whether the file is existing or not?
But I am getting an error :

```
The transaction failed: no-cache,
```

Same thing happens with:

```
 access -w filename;
```

if I want to check whether the file is writable by current user.

Also this can also easily be done with `test` command easily. Then what is the exact difference between these two commands. Please elaborate.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the output of the following commands: 1) `which access`; 2) `rpm -q --whatprovides $(which access)`; BTW, If the man you see it similar to [this one](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access), this is a c/c++ function, not a shell command...

Comment: @Oded : `which access` doesn't give the path for `access`. But my question is a lot of linux online books are identifying `access` as a linux commands.

Also it might be a c/c++ function, but i think it has some application in linux as well, as lots of other linux commands are also nothing but system calls to some c/c++ functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a Linux command. It's `C` function that can be loaded through the `unistd.h` library.

You can use it in a `C` program as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   int writeable;
   writeable = access("/path/to/file", W_OK);
   if (writeable == -1)
       printf("Not writeable!");
   else
       printf("Writeable!";

   return 0;
}
```

Note that it returns `0` on success. And `0` is false for `C` and many other languages, but in this case it means `true`.

The fact that you can see `man access` doesn't mean at all that it's a Linux command as any standard Linux distribution has man pages for every C library and function. You can also see `man malloc`. You can determine if it's a Linux command or a C library man page by viewing the header. For example `man access`:

```
ACCESS(2)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 ACCESS(2)

NAME
       access - check real user's permissions for a file

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       int access(const char *pathname, int mode);
```

As you can see, the first line states `Linux Programmer's Manual`.